# What are these brackets? What do they mean and what are they called?

Tags: notation, terminology, repeats

I came across to these brackets in my music theory book of Trinity. I don't know what are these called and what they exactly do in this music?

[image: image of bracket with 1. under it]

[image: image of bracket with 2. under it]

Answer (score 21):

These brackets indicate a "first and second ending." The measures under the "1" are to be played the first time through and those under the "2" are to be played the second time.

It's a nice method of notation and can be extended to more choices. There are also things like "dal segno" and "al fine" and others. You should check them out; search the internet for music notation.

[This link](https://www.studybass.com/lessons/reading-music/repeats-and-endings/) has a nice summary of the most basic repeats and endings.

Comment: Maybe you should add they're called "voltas", since it's still used. And more specifically prima volta and seconda volta

Comment: @Creynders  Just be sure not to confuse with "V.S." , 'volta subito,'  indicating you better turn the page quick :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft true that, maybe it should be added that volta literally means turn and hence isn't restricted to the volta lines ...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "volti subito". Volti mean turn. It's also the nickname of my electrician.

Comment: @Creynders Volta literally means time. You guys need watching :-)

Comment: Italian speaker here. Volta means may things, among whose [an] arched ceiling, [you] turn, [this] time. Volta subito: turn now. Prima volta: first time. Seconda volta: second time. By the way, Dal Segno means literally "from the sign" (da+il segno), Dal Capo: from the beginning, and Al Coda: to the "tail" = end.

Comment: @Zachiel for some reason, _da capo_ is traditionally without the definite article.

Comment: @Phoog Weird. I have some scores which have "Dal Capo" (as part of the expression "Dal Capo al Coda"). After googling, I see that it is not the standard. Both are grammatically correct, of course.

Answer (score 5):

The name is *volta* brackets. Used to mark alternate endings used in conjunction with repeat sign barlines.